# Delete old directories using cronjob is not working in LINUX

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have test this deleting directories command in LINUX terminal and it is working fine.

**find /home/TEST_*/* -maxdepth 0 -mtime +6 -exec rm -r {} ;**

**printf "deleted IPSIM old directory"**

[image]

But when i set cronjob to cleanup the directories, i get error as below.

**find: missing argument to `-exec'
deleted IPSIM old directory**

Crontab:

**00 00 * * 3 cd /home/cronjob; sh cleanup_regress_SIM.sh**

[image]

Can someone help with this and correct me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the _bash_ tag, because bash is not involved in your script.

Comment: i dont have to include the bash tag in my script?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to put that script command in crontab is:

`00 00 * * 3 /home/cronjob/cleanup_regress_SIM.sh`

In more detail:

You do not need to use `cd`, just specify the full path to the bash script.

`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` is already defined in the beginning of the script so it will run in the correct environment. No need to use `sh`

I have tested a copy of this on my own system and it works fine. I don't know what kind of system you run that throws these errors. Here is what works.

test.sh (slightly different)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(find /home/gerge/Documents/Arduino/wifi* -maxdepth 0 -mtime +30 -exec ls {} \;)>>/home/gerge/test.log
echo "command done">>/home/gerge/test.log
```

crontab (run every minute for testing)

```
*/1 * * * * /home/gerge/test.sh
```

The content of `test.log`

```
wifiConfigPortal.ino wifiRelayLogin.ino wifiRGB.ino wifiRGBsimple.ino
command done
wifiConfigPortal.ino wifiRelayLogin.ino wifiRGB.ino wifiRGBsimple.ino
command done
wifiConfigPortal.ino wifiRelayLogin.ino wifiRGB.ino wifiRGBsimple.ino
command done
```

I would recommend checking if other scripts are able to run as cronjobs. If you get the same error there is some bigger issue.

Comment: While this is true, it does not address the OP's problem.  In particular, the useless `cd` is harmless, because the `find` command in the script does not depend on the working directory.  Explicitly specifying `sh` in the crontab even has the tiny advantage, that the script would be executed even if the x- bit  has not been set.

Comment: i tried as suggested but i hit into this error,  /bin/sh: /home/cronjob/cleanup_regress_SIM.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: well that means you don't have `/bin/sh`, try with `#!/bin/bash` in the first line

Comment: @Gerge tried with what you have suggested but i get the same error, /bin/sh: /home/cronjob/cleanup_regress_SIM.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory